# How can I transfer an input from XML to Java?

Tags: java, xml, database

I don´t know what to do with that task:
I want to write a simple app with AndroidStudio and this app has the task to take a password the user gives and send this input with java and bluetooth to a microcontroller (Elegoo UNO3) with a HC-05 Bluetooth Modul to check the password (The Password is in the Microcontroller saved as Hash-Password) but I don´t know how to work with Java AND xml together could someone explain me how to take the input of the XML and copy it in a Java Object?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse XML in Java? What does taking a password from the user have to do with XML?

Comment: so you want to copy all the XML, to a java String object ? or do you want some specific element/attribute of XML to be saved to a String object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Guys thanks for your help but I found the answer.

I think it is my fault that I didnt told you guys that I use Android Studio :)

Anyways I got the Answer here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lF5m4o_CuNg

Answer (score 0):

Could you please paste your example xml structure.
Generally you can use jaxb which helps in parsing your xml into a java bean (i;e. xml to java class)

You can build your java object seeing your xsd(if you do not have xsd a complete xml will also works)

For example:
I have an xml like

```
  <root>
    <username>somename</username>
    <pwd>password</pwd>
    <url>someUrl</url>
    </root>
```

then my bean class will be like

```
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "root")
    @XmlType(propOrder = { "username", "pwd", "url"})
    public class RootTag {

    private String username;
    private String pwd;
    private String url;

    //getters and setters
```

And here is the implementation Main class which do the conversion

```
File xmlFile = new File("root.xml");

JAXBContext jaxbContext;
try
{
    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootTag.class);              

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    RootTag tag = (RootTag) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);

   // will print the pwd value
    System.out.println(tag.getPwd);
}
catch (JAXBException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late answer and thank I think it really helps me but I can´t import javax.xml.bind.*  . The .bind doesn´t seem to exist on my AndroidStudio.

Comment: Please go through this [link]{https://github.com/bunq/sdk_java/issues/111}

It seems here he got the solution for this

`I've added "implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.4'" to the build.gradle, and xercesImpl.jar from "Apache Xerces2" to the lib-directory.`